# Raspberry Pi Camera read speed too slow

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, opencv

I'm trying to write image frames from Raspberry Pi camera 1.3v. I'm using PiCamera library. When I run simple code to preview the camera, it shows frames almost real time.

```
import time
import picamera
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(10)
    camera.stop_preview()
```

But following code doesn't write frames at real time. There is about 1 second delay between frames. When using USB webcam with openCV `imwrite()`, it writes much more than that rate.

```
import time
import picamera
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    try:
        for i, filename in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous('image{counter:02d}.jpg')):
            print(filename)
            if i == 59:
                break
    finally:
        camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: Read [rapid capture and processing](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#rapid-capture-and-processing) in the picamera docs (the main thing is you're using the still port, not the video port)

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.system(raspistill)`, I'm using it a lot in python
To get it use import os and to use put `os.system("put bash command here")` try not to use sudo in your commands though